# Password saved as plain text in database Django AbstractUser

Tags: django, hash

Actually, I am working on a project and I have to modify the authentication system so that I am able to log in using email instead of a username. Also, I have to remove the username field as it's not relevant for the use case scenario. The problem i am getting is after user registers the password is saved as a plain text in database. Below is my implementation

My **views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
  
        password = request.POST['cr-pwd']
        email =  request.POST['cr-eml']
        phone_number = request.POST['cr-phone']
        print(password, email, phone_number)
        
        user = User.objects.create_user(email, password)
        # user.username = username
        user.password = password
        user.email = email
        user.phone_number = phone_number
        user.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created successfully')
        return render(request, 'index.html')


    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

My **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _




class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)



class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

#Email as auth removing username    
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


#Adding extra fields
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ("email", "password")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **_create_user** method in **models.py**, you are saving the **hashed password** correctly
but in the **signup** method in **views.py**, you are reassigning the value of the password with the plain text so simple remove that line.

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
  
        password = request.POST['cr-pwd']
        email =  request.POST['cr-eml']
        phone_number = request.POST['cr-phone']
        print(password, email, phone_number)
        
        user = User.objects.create_user(email, password)
        # user.username = username
        user.email = email
        user.phone_number = phone_number
        user.save()

        messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created successfully')
        return render(request, 'index.html')


    return render(request, 'index.html')
```